# Blinking 3 W, 12 V LED not bright

Tags: arduino, transistors, led, battery-operated

I am attempting to control the blink of an automotive brake light LED (3 W, 0.22 A @ 12 V found here- [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MY4T4BU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MY4T4BU)) for maximum brightness. I am using an Arduino Nano to manage the timing of the blink. I am using an 11 V, 5 A drone battery to power everything.

I followed the YouTube tutorial below to figure out the Arduino, then added a buck converter to provide the power for the Arduino. I am using the indicated TIP31 transistor in the schematic because it is what I had handy instead of the MOFSET from the video.

While running, I am measuring 0.1 A @ 11 V at the LED bulb. It is working, but it is very dim. I would like it to be as bright as possible.

If I plug the LED bulb directly into the battery, it is bright enough to blind you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdsp3j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit- I forgot the link to the YouTube video mentioned above- https://youtu.be/XiOcxyyTxy4?t=453 which presents the following diagram. High likelihood I got some of the schematic wrong. This is a new world for me.

I updated the schematic with the errors pointed out in the comments.

[image]

Edited Again- Tried to clear up questions / fill in missing information.

Comment: Don't put the LED in the emitter leg. It goes in the collector branch (along towards the plus end of battery.) And then ground the emitter (to the negative/minus of your battery.) You will also need a base current of about 10 mA for that device. So perhaps a 390 Ohm resistor from A3 pin to base, assuming your A3 pin can source that much. If not, you need a more complex circuit. All that assumes that the negative output of your buck converter is galvanically tied back to battery-minus.

Comment: In your schematic you show a TIP31 NPN BJT for Q1, however in the pictorial wiring diagram below you have what appears to be a MOSFET of some kind (as evidenced by the "G D S" pin labels. What exactly are you using there?

Comment: The schematic shown will work for a logic-level MOSFET e.g. IRL540 but will not work for a BJT, for which a base current limiting resistor is required. Can you provide measurements of lamp, transistor and battery voltages while on?

Answer (score 2):

If you measure 11 VDC with an 11.1 V battery, the bulb is as bright as it can be. It may be a lot brighter when connected to an automotive battery which will be at least 12.5 V and usually about 13.2 V to 14 V when charging. The bulb may have three LEDs in series with forward voltage of 3.2 V each (9.6 V total) and a series resistor that provides the rated 220 mA at 13 V, which would be 15.4 ohms. With 11 V, the bulb would draw 90 mA.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the schematic, it looks like the diode is connected backwards.
2. If the output on the buck converter is isolated from the input, then the output signal from the Arduino will not have any potential vs the diode power supply.

Comment: I was curious about different grounding scenarios, so I tried grounding R1 to the V- OUT and I tried the transistor to the V- OUT... neither seemed to have made a difference.

Comment: In terms of the diode being backwards... thats just my poor schematic knowledge. I wasn't sure which was + / - ...

Comment: @JasonRostar:  You need the converter V- and the Arduino Ground connected to the negative side of the battery.  Also the transistor is backwards - the emitter (lead with arrow) should be connected to the battery negative, with collector to the LED.

Comment: @PeterBennett Thanks! I'll try to adjust the ground. I made a correction to the schematic above.

Comment: @PeterBennett There did not seem to be any noticeable difference between adding the ground connection back to the battery source. The light / circuit is working, but is at about half brightness.